# Time complexity of a triple nested loop function

Tags: time-complexity

Looking for help on how to find time complexity here:

```
void f(int n)
{
 for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
     for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
         for(int k=i*j; k>0; k/=2)
             printf("~");
}
```

What I tried so far is noticing the inner loop runs `log(i*j)` times for `O(1)` for each received combination of `i,j`. So I got:

```
log(n(n-1))+log(n(n-2))+...+log(n)+log((n-1)(n-2))+...+log(n-1)+...+...+log(1) but I can't find how to simplify it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a specialist on this field, but maybe my consideration helps.

The two outer loops cause `n*(n - 1)/2` executions of the innermost loop.
That makes a complexity of `O(n^2)`

The innermost loop has a logarithmic complexity. And since `log(n^2) = 2log(n)`, it'll be something like `O(log(n))`, yielding a total complexity of `O(n^2 log(n))`.

If you look at your sum of logarithms, you'll find that most arguments are greater than `n`. In fact, there are `(n - 1)^2` arguments that exceed `n` and only `n - 1`arguments less than `n`.

And if you're not convinced by my reasoning above, maybe it helps if you consider that `log(a) + log(b) = log(ab)`. IOW your sum equals `log(n(n - 1)!)`